# C++ vector::front not working

Tags: c++, vector, file-handling

I'm trying to read the lines from a text file and then break each line into a vector of words. Next, I need to get the first word from each of those vector. Following is my code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    ifstream inputFile("input.txt");
    vector<string> words;
    string line, piece;

    while( getline(inputFile, line) ){

        istringstream lineStream(line);

        while( getline(lineStream, piece, ' ') ){
            words.push_back(piece);
        }

        // this does not work
        cout << words.front() << endl;

        /*
        // this works fine
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<words.size(); i++){
            cout << words[i] << endl ;
        }
        */

        words.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this what the text file contains

```
Read the lines from a file
Break each line into words
print the 1st word from each of those lines
```

This gives me the following error
[image]

This line is causing the error

```
cout << words.front() << endl;
```

I need output like this

```
Read
Break
print
```

Someone please help.!

Comment: Did you try `cout << words[0] << endl;` to get the first element? You should also be sure that the vector is not empty.

Comment: You almost certainly should NOT include `bits/stdc++.h` - anything starting with `bits` is an internal "implementation specific" header, and a) not portable, b) not necessarily "complete".

Comment: In addition to @mch: `words[0]` as well as `words.front()` fails (may crash) if `words.empty()` returns `true`. Hence, this should checked before.

Comment: the not empty trick worked.
thanks a lot
@mch

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.  Also, please stick to standard C++ headers when posting code here - `<bits/stdc++.h>` is platform-specific and will reduce the number of people likely to answer.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that the `std::vector<string> words` is indeed getting filled in the while loop ? Because if not then, you are trying to access an empty vector thereby leading to a crash.

Make a check before you access the `front()` as shown below :

```
if( !words.empty() )
    cout << words.front() << endl;
```

This would make sure that the `front()` is accessed only when the vector was filled with something meaningful.